# MySQL C# validation error

Tags: c#, mysql, validation, passwords

```
public void Find(string userName, string password)
    {
        string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE username =\'" + userName + "\', \'" + GetMd5Sum(password) + "\'";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

        try
        {

            //This will return 1 if the username and password exist.
            //It will return 0 if the username and password are not found.
            int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            if (count > 0)
                MessageBox.Show("You have succesfully logged in!");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password.");

            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I think that is where the problem is. Could anyone explain or help me out with this error?

The error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'C8059E2Ec7419F590E79D7F1B774BFE6' ' at line 1

Comment: Try putting the line `userName = "' OR 1=1 --";` at the top of the method. Then if you don't understand why that "fixed" your problem, read up on SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 5):

Your SQL looks like this (where `$user` and `$passwordhash` are the values, of course):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE username = '$user', '$passwordhash'
```

What do you expect that second value to do? I suspect you want something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE username = '$user' AND passhash = '$passwordhash'
```

(Change `passhash` based on your actual column name.)

However, you should *not* just add that text into your query. Instead, change your code to use *parameterized SQL* to avoid SQL injection attacks. *Always* use parameters instead of including values directly into your SQL:

- It avoids SQL injection attacks
- It avoids unnecessary and error-prone string conversions (particularly for date/time values)
- It keeps your code (SQL) separate from your data, making the queries easier to read

Answer (score 0):

You need an **AND** between the values in the where clause

```
string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user " + 
               "WHERE username ='" + userName + "' AND " +
               "PASSWORD ='" + GetMd5Sum(password) + "'";
```

And you did not name your password column.

Comment: You still haven't corrected the gaping SQL injection attack vector. I *really* hope the OP doesn't take the easy-but-ultimately-awful approach of *just* applying your answer.

Comment: I won't. I know about parameters, I just wanted to see if I could generally get it working first.

Comment: @user1816388: Don't do that. Firstly, the code is *clearer* with parameters... and secondly, there's a significant chance you'll never find the time to go back and do it properly. We've all left TODO in code bases - *never* do it where SQL injection is concerned.

Comment: Alright then I'll do it with parameters now.

Comment: Can you post an example of how I could do this with parameters? Execute scalar isn't working for me as even though it should return an integer, when I cast it, it gives me a error about the specified cast type.

Answer (score -2):

Your Query would look like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE username ='user', 'pass'
```

Whereas it should have been:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE username ='user' AND password='pass'
```

A little research and retrospection would have helped.